# Error #1045 Access Denied in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, wamp, mysql-error-1045

Basically I changed the password of `MySQL` via `CMD` and after that when I tried to visit the phpmyadmin page it shows me Error #1045 Access Denied.

I would like to how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Go to phpMyAdmin folder (in my case it is C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1). In the file config.inc.php change the line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'
```

Now the password will be asked on your first visit of the phpMyAdmin page

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a ton when I had a previous MySQL installation I wanted to use instead of the one bundled with WAMP.

Answer (score 5):

you have to change the database password value in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.4.5\config.inc.php into your MySQL database password

ex:-
**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourMySQLpassword';**

Answer (score 2):

Simply, clear your cache and refresh the page.  That should help you out!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the password in the PPHMyAdmin `config-db.php` file.