# Wamp Server Error #1045

Tags: php, wamp

I would like to know about the Wamp server #1045 error on my machine. few days back i had installed my Wamp server and it was working fine like loading PhpMyAdmin, creation of database, localhost etc. i even performed some basic practices in Php.

Later on i learnt to change the password of MySQL  via MySQL CMD and i performed the same. After that when i tried to load the PhpMyAdmin again, it showed me error #1045 access denied.

I tried to perform many thing but no respite from the pains. I tried to perform some fixes in phpmyadmin/config.inc, some setting in ctrl panl- Admin tools-Services-mySql (Start and stop)..

May i know what has happened to this and how to solve this problem. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287147/error1045-access-denied-in-phpmyadmin . please don't double post questions (you can edit them).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error#1045 Access Denied in PhpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287147/error1045-access-denied-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically giving yourself the answer inside your question.

You changed the mysql password. With which you most probably mean that you changed the mysql root user password. Since phpmyadmin is a mysql GUI (graphic user interface) it is only understandable that phpmyadmin can not function anymore because you haven't told it the new password you set. Just login to phpmyadmin by using 'root' as user and the new password you set. Works?

Comment: Thanks for your reply may i know where to give PhpMyadmin new-password..??

Comment: When you open the phpmyadmin page you should see a login dialog, don't you? If not, wamp does something unexpected like trying to log you in automatically. In that case you should read the wamp documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help.