# Access Denied Error whenever i am trying to login in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not able to login in mysql. i have try to login with phpmyadmin and cmd line. But every time it give me below error.

**#1045 - Access denied for user 'slaveuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

Please provide me any solution ASAP/

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error#1045 Access Denied in PhpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287147/error1045-access-denied-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is same like this question **[Error#1045 Access Denied in PhpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287147/error1045-access-denied-in-phpmyadmin)**
so please check it that answer..